# Open windows modal from windows modal in Bootstrap loading external html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to open a windows modal from a windows modal in Bootstrap, but loading the content from an external html file and having just one windows modal holder. I Load all the windows modal in the same div, and when the windows modal is closed, remove all its content.

I'm using **JQuery `load()`** method, and including the windows modal content in the `.modal-content` just like Bootstrap documentation says.

Opening all the windows modal it's ok, but if I click a link inside a windows that open another windows modal nothing happens, not even console errors.

Here is my HTML structure that will hold all my windows modals:

```
<div id="quinielaModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
$('#contacto').click(function() {
    $( "#quinielaModal .modal-content" ).load( "wm-contacto.html" );
    $('#quinielaModal').modal();

    return false;
});

$('#legales').click(function() {
    $( "#quinielaModal .modal-content" ).load( "wm-legales.html" );
    $('#quinielaModal').modal();

    return false;
});

$('.btn-login').click(function() {
    $( "#quinielaModal .modal-dialog" ).addClass('modal-chico');
    $( "#quinielaModal .modal-content" ).load( "wm-login.html" );
    $('#quinielaModal').modal();

    return false;
});

$('#quinielaModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $( "#quinielaModal .modal-dialog" ).removeClass('modal-chico');
    $('.modal-header').remove();
    $('.modal-body').remove();
});
```

Comment: I suspect the click handlers need to to be attached further up the DOM with `on` so they can catch clicks on the new ajax content.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more, what you mean? @Owlvark

Comment: If you use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), you can have click handlers for elements that have not been loaded yet.